# Launch a terminal command in Go that is defined as an alias

Tags: bash, go, terminal, alias

I am writing a program in Go that sends some commands.
I can run any command that is in the $PATH.
I check that the command is runnable with the LookPath function.

```
path, err := exec.LookPath("pwd")
```

and then run it with the following command:

```
func Run(command string, args []string) string {
    cmd := exec.Command(command, args...)

    output, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        logging.PrintlnError(fmt.Sprint(err) + ": " + string(output))
        return ""
    }
    return string(output)
}
```

The `Run("pwd", "")` is working
But if I am using an alias, it doesnt' work.

For instance, I have `alias l='ls -lah'` in my `~/.bash_aliases` file, but when I want to run that command in Go, it doesn't work.

`Run("l")` is not working.

I have the following error message :

```
exec: "l": executable file not found in $PATH:
```

I tried as well to use another method to run some alias' command.

```
func RunCmd(cmd string) string {
    out, err := exec.Command(cmd).Output()
    if err != nil {
        logging.PrintlnError("error occured")
        logging.PrintlnError(fmt.Sprint(err))
    }
    fmt.Printf("%s", out)

    return string(out)
}
```

But it is not working as well.

Do you know what function I can use to launch a command that is defined as an alias in my shell?
I tried to launch `bash -c cmd` but unfortunately as well.

Thanks

Comment: Where is your `alias` located? It should be a `.bashrc` file or other scripts. Either parse the file yourself and replace the alias with auctual command or ask bash to parse it.

Comment: My alias are located in `~/.bash_aliases` as mentioned in the question.
Does it have a more simple way to call it instead of parsing the file.

Comment: run `bash -c "source ~/.bash_aliases; cmd"`.

Comment: It does not work unfortunately.
I tried `/bin/bash -i -c cmd` as well.

Comment: Try `bash -ic -rcfile ~/.bash_alias "cmd"`.

Comment: It doesn't work as well.
I have the following error message : 
`fork/exec bash -ic -rcfile ~/.bash_aliases "cmd": no such file or directory`

Comment: It's probably not a good idea to have a Go program rely on a user having an alias defined in the first place.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to launch a command that is defined as an alias in your `~/.bashrc` or`~/.bash_aliases` files, you can use the `bash -c cmd` command described in the other comments.
Nevertheless, you must implement it in a proper way in Go.
Here is the command:

```
exec.Command("/bin/bash", "-c", "aliasCmd "+ _alias_arguments)
```

However, you should not have your program to rely on a user defined alias. ;-)

Comment: I would apreciate if you tell us how you you managed to make this work. I have tried and I haven't succeeded, which is consistent with the fact that "the underlying call out to the command is performed by Golang's os/exec module, which doesn't use a shell to execute commands, but calls the command program directly" (credits for the author of this comment: https://github.com/mmmorris1975/aws-runas/issues/16#issuecomment-402211208). No shell, no aliases.